# ¿Mostrar consecutivamente los días entre dos fechas? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación en Vb.net para unos formatos de vacaciones. El detalle que me tiene pidiendo ayuda por aquí, es que al momento de que el usuario seleccione las fechas de inicio y fin(`DateTimePicker`), un `TextBox` se llene con la información de los días seleccionados.

Pongo un ejemplo:

```
Fecha_Inicio 03/09/2018 
Fecha_final  07/09/2018
```

en el `TextBox`se debería de llenar de la siguiente forma:

```
03,04,05,06,07 de agosto
```

cuando corresponde al mismo mes (inicio y fin) o si esta entre dos meses distintos ejemplo:

```
Fecha_Inicio 24/09/2018
Fecha_final 05/10/2018
```

el `TextBox` se debería de llenar de la siguiente forma:

```
24,25,26,27,28 de agosto y 01,02,03,04,05 de octubre
```

es importante mencionar que solo se contarían los días hábiles (lunes a viernes), de antemano agradezco la atención, esperando pudieran orientarme para encontrar una posible solución.

**Pikoh** agradezco tu observación lo de los días hábiles lo tengo de la siguiente forma;

```
    Dim Cant As Integer = 1
    Dim Ini As DateTime = dtpIni.Value               
    Dim Fin As Date = dtpFin.Value                    

    While Ini <> Fin
        If Not (Ini.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Or Ini.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Then
            Cant = Cant + 1
        End If
        Ini = Ini.AddDays(1)
    End While
    Label3.Visible = True
    Label3.Text = Cant
```

con esto logro que me cuente el total de los días tomados sin contar los sábados y domingos entre las fechas, donde ya me atore como lo mencione anteriormente es en que muestre consecutivamente los días entre las fechas seleccionadas del `DateTimePicker` intente con una pequeña `funcion`

```
 Dim Array() As String = {"CERO", "UNO", "DOS", "TRES", "CUATRO", "CINCO", "SEIS", "SIETE", "OCHO", "NUEVE", "DIEZ", "ONCE", "DOCE", "TRECE", "CATORCE", "QUINCE", "DIECISÉIS", "DIECISIETE", "DIECIOCHO", "DIECINUEVE", "VEINTE", "VEINTIUNO", "VEINTIDÓS", "VEINTITRES", "VEINTICUATRO"}
    Dim vNombres() As Object
    vNombres = Array
    fechas = UCase(vNombres(Format(dFecha, "dd") - 1) & " de " & (Format(dFecha, "MMMM")) & " de dos mil " & vNombres(Year(dFecha) - 2001))
```

Cambiando la parte del `string` por los números, pero ya no supe como.

**gbianchi** esta ultima parte es solo un ejemplo de una `funcion` que tengo y que efectivamente me cambiaba las fechas a letras por asi decirlo, lo que ahora necesito es:

Pongo un ejemplo:

```
Fecha_Inicio 03/09/2018 
Fecha_final  07/09/2018
```

en el `TextBox`se debería de llenar de la siguiente forma:

```
03,04,05,06,07 de agosto
```

cuando corresponde al mismo mes (inicio y fin) o si esta entre dos meses distintos ejemplo:

```
Fecha_Inicio 24/09/2018
Fecha_final 05/10/2018
```

el `TextBox` se debería de llenar de la siguiente forma:

```
24,25,26,27,28 de agosto y 01,02,03,04,05 de octubre
```

Perdón si no me eh sabido explicar, la `función` anterior fue solo un ejemplo si se podría implementar algo parecido.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Lo que pides no es nada complicado, pero la norma en [es.so] es no realizar las tareas por otra persona sin mas. Necesitamos ver si has intentado algo, con que problemas te has encontrado, etc...Te aconsejo que pulses en [edit] y añadas toda esta información a tu pregunta.

Comment: **SdeSistemas** excelente es lo que estaba buscando, solo le agregare un detallito menor.

Comment: **gbianchi** me ayudaste igualmente es también lo que estaba buscando, agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu última edición te puedo sugerir una solución: Utilizando Diccionario para almacenar los meses y dias seleccionados de ese mes.

Declarar variables a usar:

```
Dim Cant As Integer = 0                         ' Almacenar total de dias 
Dim Ini As DateTime = dtpIni.Value              ' Fecha Inicial
Dim Fin As DateTime = dtpFin.Value              ' Fecha Final
Dim diferencia As TimeSpan = Fin.Subtract(Ini)  ' Diferencia entre el rango 
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String)    ' Diccionario.
```

Cambio tu `While` por un `for` para recorrer los dias que existen del rango seleccionado

```
For i As Integer = 0 To diferencia.TotalDays
   Dim fecha As DateTime = Ini.AddDays(i)

     If Not (fecha.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or fecha.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) Then
          Cant = Cant + 1 ' Sumar contador
          ' Uso de diccionario, almacenar nombre del mes (ejemplo: septiembre) y los dias seleccionados del mismo (ejemplo: 04, 05, 06, 07, 10, 11)
          Dim currentValueA As String = If(dic.ContainsKey(MonthName(fecha.Month)), dic.Item(MonthName(fecha.Month)), "")
                If dic.ContainsKey(MonthName(fecha.Month)) Then
                    dic.Item(MonthName(fecha.Month)) = currentValueA & ", " & fecha.ToString("dd")
                Else
           ' Agregar en el dicionario los valores.
                    dic.Add(MonthName(fecha.Month), currentValueA & " " & fecha.ToString("dd"))
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Lo último es recorrer el diccionario para sacar los datos y almacenarlos en un TextBox

```
 Dim strCadena As String = ""
 For Each item In dic
   strCadena += item.Value & " de " & item.Key
 Next
 TextBox1.Text = strCadena
 MsgBox(Cant)
```

> Prueba:

```
Ini = "14/9/2018"
Fin = "6/10/2018"
```

Caja de texto = `14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 de septiembre 01, 02, 03, 04, 05 de octubre`

Cant = `16`

Espero te pueda servir en lo que vayas a realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Cree este pequeño programa de consola que te lo soluciona.

```
Dim Cant As Integer = 1
Dim Ini As Date = New Date(2018, 3, 1)
Dim Fin As Date = New Date(2018, 6, 15)

Dim MesActual As Integer = Ini.Month
Dim cadena As String = ""
While Ini <> Fin
    If Not (Ini.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Or Ini.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Then
        Cant = Cant + 1
        'lo agrego a la cadena
        cadena = cadena & Ini.Day & ","
    End If
    Ini = Ini.AddDays(1)
    If MesActual <> Ini.Month Then
        MesActual = Ini.Month
        'puntos extra, si hay mas de dos meses, reemplazo ## por ,
        cadena = Replace(cadena, "##", ", ")
        'reemplazo el ultimo caracter para poner el mes.
        cadena = Mid(cadena, 1, Len(cadena) - 1) & " de " & Format(Ini.AddMonths(-1), "MMMM") & "##"
    End If
End While
'agrego el ultimo mes
cadena = Mid(cadena, 1, Len(cadena) - 1) & " de " & Format(Ini, "MMMM")
cadena = Replace(cadena, "##", " y ")
Console.WriteLine(cadena)
Console.ReadLine()
```

La idea atras de este programa, es solamente recorrer una vez lo que necesitas y generar la cadena a medida que lo vas recorriendo.

Fijate que aprovecho lo que tenias, para ir agregando los numeros de dias a la cadena. y despues cada vez que sumo un dia, verifico que no hayas cambiado de mes. Si cambiaste de mes, entonces agrego ese mes a la cadena (fijate que hice un toquecito para que si saltara mas de un mes, agregue una coma entre los meses) y entre los dos ultimos meses, pone una y

Comment: **gbianchi** excelente opcion solo encontre un detalle en                          
       `Dim Ini As Date = New Date(2018, 3, 1)
       Dim Fin As Date = New Date(2018, 6, 15)`    'si colocas la misma fecha al mes final marca error, pues no toma encuentra que en teoría seria un solo día el tomado

Comment: ah si si.. no comprobe eso.. bastaria con verificar si cadena es vacio al salir del while, y si es asi imprimir directamente ese string. tenes razon, ahora lo agrego..